# Application has not been registered (react-native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know this question has been asked a couple times, but I can't seem to get the problem fixed.

I keep getting the error "Application Dropped(my app name) has not been registered" after trying to implement tab navigation. I restart my command prompts and my AppRegistry.registerComponent and MainActivity.java seem to be correct, so I don't believe those are the problems.

index.js

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Dropped', () => App);
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "Dropped";
}
```

I am currently testing on a physical android device. I'm very new to react so I'm sorry if I'm overlooking something obvious.

router.js (navigation)

```
import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

import Search from '../screens/Search';
import Categories from '../screens/Categories';
import Watching from '../screens/Watching';

export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
Watching: {
    screen: Watching,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Watching",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="eye" size={35} color={tintColor}/>
    }
},
Categories: {
    screen: Categories,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Categories",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" size={35} color={tintColor}/>
    }
},
Search: {
    screen: Search,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Search",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="magnifying-glass" size={35} color={tintColor}/>
    }
},
tabBarPosition: "bottom",
});
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs } from "./app/config/router";

export default class App extends React.Component 
{
    render() 
    {
        return (<Tabs/>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because the metro bundler for the app is not running . just close the currently running bundler or process in the terminal and then restart the application again.It will work like a charm